# How to check if a file exists in a war file?

Tags: java, file, file-io

How can I check if a file exists in a war file?  I know I can use

```
boolean doesExist = new File(myfile).exists();
```

but how do I use that in a java class in the war?  The file.getAbsolutePath() just shows where the war file is running.  I need to check if there is an image in another directory in the war that matchs the filename in the war so I can display that or a generic image if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ServletContext.getResource()`

From javadoc:

> This method returns null if no resource is mapped to the pathname.

Answer (score 6):

Below is an approach you should use *only* if your war is not deployed and you want to check it via some external tool.

If the war is deployed, and you have a `ServletContext` available, then use it instead (as shown in axtavt's answer)

A `war` file is a zip file, so you can read it with the `java.util.zip` package, 
Using [ZipFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html):

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("/path/to/archive.war");
ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry("yourSearchedEntry");
if (entry == null) {
   // the file is not found in the war.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getServletContext().getRealPath("/")

```
File f = new File(session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/myFile.ext");
if (f.exists()) {
.......
}
```